# Rails: Creating a routing path for each row of a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a table called Partners, with a column called Partner Name. I want to create a URL for each partner that looks something like this: `www.url.com/partner/PartnerName`.

Now I have been trying to do something like this in my `routes.rb`

```
  get '/partner/:partner_name', to: 'pages#partner_page'
```

And in my controller, I do

```
logger.info params[:partner_name]
```

which is always nil. The thing is I know this works for ids because I have done it before. If it were to be

```
get '/partner/:id', to: 'pages#partner_page'
```

I know that `logger.info params[:id]` would have worked. But in this case, it isn't.

Apart from this problem, I would like the URL to be routed to the page, only if that particular partner name exists. But this is a check I can do only in the controller, by which time the page is already rendered. How do I fix the above issues?

Comment: what is your link code? how do you send the partner_name param from link to controller? Your link should be like: `link_to 'action', some_path(partner_name: 'partnername')`

Comment: Ahhh. I did not have this link code. Honestly, I'm not familiar with how it works. Thanks for this hint though!

Comment: you need to send parter_name from your link_to helper to your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**routes.rb**

`get '/partner/:partner_name', to: 'pages#partner_page', as: :partner_page`

this will give you `partner_page_path` route available.

**html.erb**

`link_to partner.name, partner_page_path(partner_name: partner.name)`

---

**controller**

```
@partners = Partner.all
```

**html.erb**

```
<% @partners.each do |partner|%>
  <%= link_to partner.name, partner_page_path(partner_name: partner.name) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't have access to partner.name in my html.erb file. I see a undefined local variable or method `partner' error. I'm sure I'm missing something here.. How do I make partner.name available in the html.erb? Can I just do @partner in the controller?

Comment: partner.name was just an example, you have to use your attribute from db that you have for partner, might be title, first_name, last_name, whatever

Comment: Yes, I got that part. Was just wondering about accessing the Partner object itself. Guess I would have to do it in the controller.